# Menu in MapView to return to a specific url in a WebView

Tags: java, android, maps

I have the following menu in my FriendApp that uses an Intent to call a MapView.  When I get to the FriendMaps I recreate the menu, but now wondering if I can return to a different page in my webview - I accomplish this in the webview menu by using loadUrl(); but not sure how to do this coming from the map view.

FriendApp Menu:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case FRIENDS:
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/myfrienddash2.php");
        return true;
    case MAP:
        Intent friendMap = new Intent(FriendApp.this, FriendMaps.class);
        startActivity(friendMap);
        return true;
    case SEARCH:
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/myfrienddash3.php");
        return true;
    case INFO:
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/myfrienddash4.php");
        return true;
    case QUIT:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then once in the FriendMaps I just mimic that menu, but need to figure out how to return to different pages, instead of just loading the webview's "main page".

FriendMaps menu:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case FRIENDS:
        Intent friendApp = new Intent(FriendMaps.this, FriendApp.class);
        startActivity(friendApp);
        return true;
    case MAP:
        return true;
    case SEARCH:
        Intent friendApp2 = new Intent(FriendMaps.this, FriendApp.class);
        startActivity(friendApp2);
        return true;
    case INFO:
        Intent friendApp3 = new Intent(FriendMaps.this, FriendApp.class);
        startActivity(friendApp3);
        return true;
    case QUIT:
        finish();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So I need to figure out how to get my maps menu working like the first menu.

Comment: After further testing with that set up above, it won't work.  If I load the map, then load the menu, then choose quit, it quits the map view and returns to the webview.  I need to figure out how to get my menu to be global across all views, anyone point me the right way?

Comment: Ok to solve my above comment I am just calling finish(); after each Intent - this way there is always only one view on the stack so at any point QUIT will properly finish(); the application.  But I am still stuck on the original question - through an Intent can I pass a specific URL to the webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the "best" way, but I figured it out and its working nicely.  In my map menu, when I create the Intents I am putting data to identify where its coming from then in my Friend activity I manage which case is starting the activity and display accordingly.

IE:

```
Intent friendApp = new Intent(FriendMaps.this, FriendApp.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("SEARCH", "search data");
friendApp.putExtras(b);
startActivity(friendApp);
```

One thing to note is I have to do some null management in my FriendApp to ensure I don't get a nullexception when using getString.